# In-situ combustion model - molar balance equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

I need to understand the following model for in-situ combustion (1). The second of these is a molar balance equation.

[image][image][image]

Well, I've tried to use the following general balance equation:

[image]

Where $r$ is the rate of reaction and the $N$ is in moles (as mass).

I think that in case of the work there is no flow of immobile fuel inlet and outlet, so I think I could clear the two initial terms.

If $ \rho_f $ is the molar concentration of the fuel, the reaction rate in relation to the fuel is given by

$$ \dfrac {\partial \rho_f} {\partial t} = - k \rho_f ^ {\mu_f} $$

(as it is an elementary reaction, the order of the reaction in relation to the fuel is the coefficient itself)

The constant is given by the Arrhenius law:

$$ k_p ~ exp (-E_r / (RT)) $$

Therefore, considering $ \mu_f = 1 $, we have equation

$$ \dfrac {\partial \rho_f} {\partial t} = - k_p ~ exp (-E_r / (RT)) \rho_f = -W_r $$

Although it matches with the article if $ \mu_f = 1 $, I do not understand why in the article $ \mu_f $ is multiplying instead of being in the exponent.

Many thanks for any help!

---

(1) G. Chapiro, A.E.R. Gutierrez, J. Herskovits, S.R. Mazorche, W.S. Pereira (2016): "Numerical Solution of a Class of Moving BoundaryProblems with a Nonlinear Complementarity Approach", *J. Optim. Theory Appl.* **168**(2), 534-550. [doi:10.1007/s10957-015-0816-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10957-015-0816-7)

Comment: This is actually a [chemical kinetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_kinetics) question. It may be that the authors mixed up stoichiometric coefficient and partial order of reaction (which are often different).

Comment: Many thanks, it may be as you say.